# Set HTML text input to null with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using JQuery event handlers I want to adjust the default value of a HTML text input and set it to empty.

The input

```
<button id="setColor">Set Color</button>
<input type="text" id="colorText">
```

The function

```
$("#setColor").on("click", function ()
{
    document.getElementById('#colorText').defaultValue = "";
});
```

I have also tried

```
$("#colorText").defaultValue = "";
$("#colorText").val = "";
$("#colorText").value = "";
```

but every time I click the SetColor button it seems to keep its previously set default value.

```
document.getElementById('colorText').defaultValue = "#0000ff";
```

Comment: Isn't `.val` a method?  So wouldn't you use `$('#colorText').val('')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('colorText').value = '';
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not cleared to me, But i got a simple mistake in your code, you write extra # in getElementById

try this:

```
$("#setColor").on("click", function ()
{
    document.getElementById('colorText').value = "";
});
```

Are you trying to reset the textbox color or want to reset the value?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#colorText").val("");
```

You can try this with jquery.